# Django - How to render a view without including a prefix to the URL?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have an entry in my urls.py:

`url(r'^user/(?P<username>\w+)$', views.user_show, name='user_name'),`

The problem is, whenever the view is rendered, the static files (CSS, Javascript etc) fail to load because Django prepends the URL match to the requests for the static files. So instead of requesting:

`http://localhost:8000/static/myapp/css/main.css`

it requests:

`http://localhost:8000/user/static/myapp/css/main.css`

Is there a way to stop the regex match from affecting the URL requests?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you getting the url for the static files? You're probably requesting  `static/myapp/css/main.css` instead of `/static/myapp/css/main.css`.

Comment: What do you have stored for ```STATIC_URL``` in your settings?

Comment: @schillingt  settings.py: STATIC_URL = '/static/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using this to load the css file in the template?

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href='{% static "css/main.css" %}'/>
```

Comment: Ah! That was it thanks. I had hard-coded urls in my base.html instead of using django to load the files.

Comment: @BelegNeurion can you approve please? :)